# Unable to create new project in AWS

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services

When I try to create new AWS java web project in Eclipse EE with AWS SDK installed, I am getting this error.

```
Unable to create new AWS Java web project.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.AwsToolkitCore.getAccountManager()Lcom/amazonaws/eclipse/core/preferences/accounts/PluginPreferenceStoreAccountManager;
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.elasticbeanstalk.webproject.CreateNewAwsJavaWebProjectRunnable.run(CreateNewAwsJavaWebProjectRunnable.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Where is your code? It's really hard to guess what is the problem, if you look for a real answer.

Comment: Looks like a jar version mismatch. It's looking for a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: There is no code ...!!......I just want to create a new AWS web java project....

Answer (score 0):

Problem is corrected by an update made available overnight (Sunday 13 April) - Just check for updates in Eclipse and download the latest version of the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse.

Please accept our apologies for the inconvenience

Seb

Comment: Thanks for looking into the problem..what should I do right now then...?

should I need to download old AWS sdk...?